# Why can't I skip ahead on a song or podcast in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, podcasts

All of a sudden, while playing a song on the itunes store or a podcast on the podcast store, I can't skip ahead to a specific time.

When I click ahead, the cursor reaches that location, then immediately pulls back and fast forwards the play location by about 5 seconds.

This is extremely frustrating and is seemingly happening out of no where.

Comment: Are the songs saved locally or is it happening on files from cloud/iTunes match, etc.?

Comment: It was happening on the store. However once I downloaded the podcast it let me skip anywhere I chose. I do remember it allowing me to skip to anywhere while still in preview though.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue. When you play a song in the store does it immediately start playing or do you have to wait? What's your result on a speed test?

Comment: It plays instantaneously.

Comment: I've found similar on YouTube videos. Workaround is to pause playback, skip to where you want, start playback.

Comment: Tried that. When I do that, it goes back to original location in time when pressing play on the video.